# Undo artist / album change in Music

Tags: music.app

I accidentally changed the artist and album of every track in my Music library.  How do I change it back?  This is Music 1.0.6.10 on Catalina.

Comment: How did you manage to change it? Did you immediately try Cmd/Z?

Comment: I selected all the tracks with cmd +a and made the changes.  It’s far from immediate now 

Comment: Time Machine then.